# How to start IPython kernel and connect using ZMQ sockets?

Tags: python, c++, qt, ipython, zeromq

I am working on a frontend to IPython in C++ (Qt).

I managed to embed Python in my application and retrieve plots and show these in my GUI. Now I want to start an IPython kernel and connect to it through ZMQ sockets.

I found a [description](https://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/messaging.html) for the communication protocol with IPython kernels. However, it doesn't say **anywhere** which ports to connect to. So it's nice and dandy to have a communication protocol, but totally useless if I don't know which ports to use.

The documentation mentions 'kernel specs' and tells me to use the `jupyter kernelspec list` command. This indeed shows me one directory, which only contains two files: logo-32x32.png and logo-64x64.png ...

How do I find the ports I need to connect to, to communicate with my IPython kernels?

I start my IPython kernel by running the following Python code from my C++ Qt app:

```
import IPython
IPython.start_kernel(argv=[])
```

Comment: Take a look at my updated version of [`ipy_repl.py`](https://gist.github.com/MattDMo/6cb1dfbe8a124e1ca5af) from the [SublimeREPL](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeREPL) plugin for the [Sublime Text](https://sublimetext.com) programming editor. There's no Sublime-specific API stuff in there. Basically, it works with IPython up to 4.1.1 and jupyter_console up to 4.1.0 (it doesn't seem to work with later versions of IPython 4 or any version of 5) to set up a connection in a Sublime view with a running IPython/Jupyter kernel, including utilizing its autocomplete capability.

Comment: `start_kernel` starts a kernel in the current process. What it sounds like you want is a kernel in a separate process which you connect to from your application process. For that, you'd use the [jupyter_client](http://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/manager.html) module. You could look at applications like Spyder to see what they do.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out Thomas K was right. The right approach to start an IPython/Jupyter kernel in a different process is: (with python3 as example)

```
import jupyter_client
kernel_manager, kernel_client = jupyter_client.start_new_kernel(kernel_name='python3')
```

When I initially tried this, I got a permission error. This was fixed by installing the python3 kernel spec (apparently Jupyter does not do this automatically...):

```
python3 -m ipykernel install --user
```

And then you can get the ports by

```
print(kernel_manager.get_connection_info())
```

It should be possible to use these ports to connect to the kernel via zero-mq. However, the `kernel_client` exposes a few methods to communicated with the kernel, so it may be easier to use that approach...